# Remove from wishlist URL?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, catalog, magento-enterprise, wishlist

I'm trying to create a link to remove an item from the wishlist if it's there. The URL is returning /wishlist/index/remove instead of the correct URL which from what I've seen online should be /wishlist/index/remove/item/[ID]. Trying that URL manually doesn't work. This is my way of getting the remove URL:

```
$_wishlistRemoveUrl = $this->helper('wishlist')->getRemoveUrl($_product);
```

Comment: why do you have both `magento-1.7` and `magento-enterprise` tags?

Comment: Were using EE but the answers for CE work just as well.

Comment: Then it makes no sense to mention any of them ;)

Comment: Generally if you're asking a question then you're probably not sure if it will apply to both EE and CE, and seeing as wishlists apply to both versions I don't see any harm in tagging this with both EE and CE tags. I think this question should definitely have a `catalog` tag though, as you're trying to display wishlist remove URLs on catalog pages. No biggie, just makes it easier for people to find in the future.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The parameters are `$_product->getId()` and `$_product->getStoreId()` Right? I'm trying to find remove_id. Becauce remove links almost same but remove_id. How can I find remove_id in this link: xx.com/wishlist/index/remove/item/$remove_id/ ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, an overview of how wishlists work:

1. Each wishlist is stored in the database with its own ID
2. Each product added to a wishlist is assigned a `wishlist_item_id`
3. This ID is not the same as the `product_id`

For this reason you can't just pass in a product ID to the remove URL because it's actually referencing the product's `wishlist_item_id`.

This explains why you are getting a blank url ("/wishlist/index/remove"), because when you pass in the product it doesn't have the required `wishlist_item_id`, you have to retrieve this in a different way.

To get around this, there is a method in `Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item` you can use to get a wishlist item by product ID:

```
    /** @var $_wishlistHelper Mage_Wishlist_Helper_Data */
    $_wishlistHelper = $this->helper('wishlist');

    /** @var $_wishlist Mage_Wishlist_Model_Wishlist */
    $_wishlist = $_wishlistHelper->getWishlist();

    /** @var $_wishlistItem Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item */
    $_wishlistItem = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item');
    $_wishlistItem->loadByProductWishlist(
        $_wishlist->getId(),
        $_product->getId(),
        $this->helper('core')->getStoreId()
    );

    $_wishlistRemoveUrl = $_wishlistHelper->getRemoveUrl($_wishlistItem);
```

Or the shorter way:

```
    $_wishlistItem = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->loadByProductWishlist(
        $this->helper('wishlist')->getWishlist()->getId(),
        $_product->getId(),
        $_product->getStoreId()
    );
    $_wishlistRemoveUrl = $this->helper('wishlist')->getRemoveUrl($_wishlistItem);
```

This code has been tested in blocks of type `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` and `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`

Comment: that was an excellent answer. Thanks for explaining that to me more and your solutions work perfectly!