# Getting id from wishlist product remove link

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, wishlist

I read this [Remove from wishlist URL?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/remove-from-wishlist-url) but I have a problem with.

I'm trying to find $removeID in this link: xx.com/wishlist/index/remove/item/$removeID/

Because wishlist remove url almost same. Only difference is $removeID

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Are you looking for the numeric ID in an existing URL?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to find numeric ID in wishlist remove link.

Comment: I've posted some code in an answer

Comment: did you manage to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

In case you're trying to find the ID from a string that holds the URL use a preg_match

```
$url = 'xx.com/wishlist/index/remove/item/5/';
preg_match('/item\/([0-9]+)/', $url, $matches);
var_dump($matches); // just will hold a multidimensional array with your ID
```

If you're trying to get the ID from a url you can use

```
$id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('item');
var_dump($id); // this will be the id
```

Comment: Actually, sorry. I can't tell very well. I'm trying to find remove link for remove product from wishlist.